Firefox | HTMLVideoElement currentTime 0 after executing play()
In Firefox web browser when I check HTMLVideoElement currentTime I got 0 even after executing play() method on it:
private async playVideo(): Promise<void> {
  this.htmlVideoElement.muted = true;
  try {
    await this.htmlVideoElement.play();
    console.log('Current time: ', this.htmlVideoElement.currentTime); // 0 in Firefox
    this.cdr.detectChanges();
  } catch (err) { console.log('Error: ', err) }
}

Any idea why is this happening only in Firefox?

What are you expecting? You are logging the currentTime right after starting the playback, so 0 or a number close to 0 is what I would expect. After the video has played for some time, the currentTime should be updated accordingly.

I am expecting "a number close to 0", as I get it in Chrome.
I am using this piece of code to check if video is playing:
!!(video.currentTime > 0 && !video.paused && !video.ended && video.readyState > 2)
source

It seems like you are currently relying on the Chrome specific implementation of the .play() function, where the currentTime is greater than 0 right after the function was called. But there is no guarantee that it's consistent across the browsers. You should delay this check.
private async playVideo(): Promise<void> {
  this.htmlVideoElement.muted = true;
  try {
    await this.htmlVideoElement.play();
    // delay by 1 millisecond
    await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 1));
    // Now the currentTime should be consistently above 0
    console.log('Current time: ', this.htmlVideoElement.currentTime);
in Firefox
    this.cdr.detectChanges();
  } catch (err) { console.log('Error: ', err) }
}


This will do the trick. I think the problem here is actually Reduced time precision

Can someone help me find the Firefox HTMLMediaElement.play() implementation in GitHub?
